# Text showing misaligned in Vim vs Cat

Tags: vim, indentation, vim-plugin

I've been using vim for a few weeks, and so far I've downloaded a few plugins including airline, nerdtree, and a colorscheme. When I downloaded some files with wget, I noticed that they weren't properly aligned. Text in the code files are normally supposed to be aligned in columns, and there generally shjouldn't be issues with indentation. As an example, when I try running the command `cat filename.extension`, I get this:

[image]

This is how the file is supposed to look. Everything is aligned neatly into columns without any issues. However, if I try editing the file in Vim, it instead looks like this:

[image]

The text for whatever reason is not aligned properly, and so far I am not sure how to resolve it...

Comment: Are you perhaps using tab for aliment instead of spaces?

Comment: Can we see your `vimrc` and the file in question?

Answer (score 2):

- The file appears to be using tabulations for indentation and alignment.
- The de-facto standard width of a tabulation is 8 characters.
- `cat` respects that "standard" to the letter, without the possibility of changing the tabulation width.
- Vim also respects it by default but it allows the user to change the tabulation width and you tell it to use a tabulation width of 4 characters.
- The file looks different because the two programs have different tabulation settings.
- Therefore, if you want the file to look the same in the two programs, use the same tabulation settings. Since they can't be changed in `cat`, you  will have to revert Vim's to their default values.

  You didn't show us your `vimrc` so we don't know exactly what you did and we can't really tell you how to go about it.